# SQL left join only returns one row instead of many

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two tables, one with cities (id and city name) and one with pictures of the cities (city_id, etc).

Let's say I'm looking for the city called Sibiu. That should return 3 results, since there are more cities like that in the table (Miercurea Sibiului, Sibiu, Poiana Sibiului), but it only returns one.

Also, as a note, the timeline_elements doesn't have any pictures of the city yet.

```
SELECT cities_countries.*, COUNT(timeline_elements.city_id) as number_of_photos 
FROM cities_countries   
LEFT JOIN timeline_elements on (cities_countries.id = timeline_elements.city_id)
WHERE cities_countries.name LIKE '%Sibiu%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `GROUP BY` and also explicitly mention all the column names for the `cities_countries` table. I consider these are the columns in the `cities_countries` table. `id, city_id, city_name`.

Also set alias name for each table for the better readability.

```
SELECT C.id, C.city_id, C.city_name, ....
       , COUNT(T.city_id) as number_of_photos 
FROM cities_countries C  
LEFT JOIN timeline_elements T ON C.id = T.city_id
WHERE C.name LIKE '%Sibiu%'
GROUP BY C.id, C.city_id, C.city_name, ....
```

Comment: This worked, however I don't understand what I did wrong. Could you take some time to explain? Thanks a lot

Comment: @SimeriaIonut [Aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173454.aspx) perform calculation and return single value alone, if you want to return the remaining columns you need to add the GROUP BY. So the columns you mentioned in the SELECT are need to include in the GROUP BY except the aggregate column name